# Not able to emulate ios with Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I'm going through the beginner series for a Cordova application. I installed XCode and created a new Cordova project. That being said, when I run `cordova emulate ios`, I get the following error:

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-X, 12.1 simulator
/Users/osx/Code/cordova-poc/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app/Info.plist file not found.
```

If I run `cordova build ios` and run the code in XCode, then I can see that Xcode opens up the emulator where I can see my changes. This is, obviously, too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're running XCode 10. XCode 10 has a new build system which is not yet supported by Cordova.

You should be able to work around this by running the following:

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

More information in this issue here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

Answer (score 4):

As stated

> Xcode 10 uses a new build system by default (previously available on
>   an opt-in basis in Xcode 9). The cordova-ios project structure is not
>   compatible with this new build system and results in failures.
>   [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407)

**1 CLI WORKAROUND**

```
# Cordova CLI
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'

# Ionic CLI
ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

**2 CONFIG FILE WORKAROUND**

```
"buildFlag": [
  "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
]
```

*In your build.json config file.*

**3 XCODE WORKAROUND**
[image]
[image]
Thanks to @kitolog for the screens.

Comment: 2. CONFIG FILE WORKAROUND, where we find build.json?