# No target specified for emulator (CORDOVA)

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Cannot get `cordova emulate ios` to open up emulator and run my application.

I continue getting the same error:

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-X, 12.1 simulator
/Users/osx/Code/react-cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator/CreateReactAppAndCordova.app/Info.plist file not found.
```

That being said, I open up XCode and build within XCode to see the application. Is there a step that I'm missing?

I've started from this base repo: https://github.com/sriramrudraraju/create-react-app-and-cordova

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to emulate ios with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090035/not-able-to-emulate-ios-with-cordova)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```

Comment: this logs: `Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.`. But it did build, though.